# Could not Initialize GLX after Conda Update --All

Tags: python, keras, spyder, glx

### Problem Description

I'm using Spyder on a remote server by SSH and X11 forwarding. After I use `conda update --all` , spyder stopped launching and has the error: Could not initialize GLX.
I have tried adding these lines in start.py

`import ctypes
ctypes.CDLL("libGL.so.1", mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets`

and also

`export __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia`

but none of them works.

I also tried

`conda install qt=5.6.2`

to downgarde qt but then I  encounter the segmentation fault.

#### What steps reproduce the problem?

1. Create a new environment
2. Install keras, keras gpu, tensorflow, tensorflow gpu, cudatoolkit and dependencies
3. Conda update --all

### Versions

About Spyder...
or (if Spyder won't launch) the "conda list" command
from the Anaconda Prompt/Terminal/command line. --->

- Spyder version: 3.2.8
- Python version: 3.6
- Qt version: 5.9.5
- PyQt version: 5.9.2
- Operating System name/version: CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3226#issuecomment-533467599 ?

---

I had this problem, spyder was not starting when using a ssh connection and I had the error : 
`Could not initialize GLX.`
This was because the qt version was to recent  : 5.9

I could not solve it by installing pyopengl, nor any other fixes that I found on the web.
Simply installing qt 5.6.2 (with conda -c conda-forge) did not work either because it downgraded my version of matplotlib to 2.2

I got it working by **reinstalling a full conda environment** to make sure I have the matplotlib version that I wanted : 3.1.1

`conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib=3.1 qt=5.6.2 spyder`